# Datepicker is not working when created it dynamically use javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm making a page, where one of the forms uses a datepicker and I make it dynamically. The first form works fine but when adding a new form the datepicker does not display anything. Here is my code with an application screenshot

Here is the javascript code, I place it in Header

```
    var room2 = 1;
    function tambah_kegiatan() {
        room2++;
        var objTo = document.getElementById('tambah_kegiatan');
        var datepicker = document.getElementById('reservation2');
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room2);
        var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room2;
        divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="card-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group "><label for="inputEstimatedBudget">Nama Agenda</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="namaAgenda[]" placeholder="Nama Agenda" required></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group "><label for="inputEstimatedBudget">Tipe Kegiatan</label><select class="form-control select2bs4" style="width: 100%;" name="tipeKegiatan[]"> @foreach($agenda_kegiatan as $agenda_kegiatan2) <option value={{ $agenda_kegiatan2->id_agenda_kegiatan }}>{{ $agenda_kegiatan2->nama_kegiatan }} </option> @endforeach </select></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group "><label for="inputEstimatedBudget">Kode Kegiatan</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="kodeKegiatan[]" placeholder="Kode Kegiatan" required></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="inputDescription">Waktu Penelitian</label><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span></div><input type="text" class="form-control float-right" id="reservation2" name="reservation2[]"></div></div></div><div class="form-group "><label class="form-control-label text-muted" style="opacity: 0;">Tambah</label><div class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="tambah_kegiatan();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> + </span> </button></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="form-control-label text-muted" style="opacity: 0;">Kurang</label><div class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_tambah_kegiatan('+room2+');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> - </span></button></div></div></div></div>';

        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    }
    function remove_tambah_kegiatan(rid) {
        $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
    }
```

Here is the php code

```
       <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card card-secondary">
              <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Agenda Penelitian</h3>

                  <div class="card-tools">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                      <i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group ">
                              <label for="inputEstimatedBudget">Nama Agenda</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namaAgenda[]" placeholder="Nama Agenda" required>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group ">
                              <label for="inputEstimatedBudget">Tipe Kegiatan</label>
                              <select class="form-control select2bs4" style="width: 100%;" name="tipeKegiatan[]">
                                  @foreach($agenda_kegiatan as $agenda_kegiatan)
                                      <option value={{ $agenda_kegiatan->id_agenda_kegiatan }}>{{ $agenda_kegiatan->nama_kegiatan }} </option>
                                  @endforeach
                              </select>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group ">
                              <label for="inputEstimatedBudget">Kode Kegiatan</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kodeKegiatan[]" placeholder="Kode Kegiatan" required>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputDescription">Waktu Penelitian</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control float-right" id="reservation2" name="reservation2[]">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group ">
                          <label class="form-control-label text-muted" style="opacity: 0;">Tambah</label>
                          <div class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="tambah_kegiatan();"> 
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> + </span> 
                              </button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="form-control-label text-muted" style="opacity: 0;">Kurang</label>
                          <div class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_tambah_kegiatan('+room2+');">
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> - </span>
                              </button>
                          </div>
                      </div> -->
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div id="tambah_kegiatan">

            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the Datepicker code, I place it in the Footer

```
<script>
var startDate;
var endDate;

$(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2').select2()

    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2bs4').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap4'
    })

    //Datemask dd/mm/yyyy
    $('#datemask').inputmask('dd/mm/yyyy', { 'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy' })
    //Datemask2 mm/dd/yyyy
    $('#datemask2').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', { 'placeholder': 'mm/dd/yyyy' })
    //Money Euro
    $('[data-mask]').inputmask()

    //Date range picker
    $('#reservation').daterangepicker()
    //Date range picker
    $('#reservation2').daterangepicker()
    //Date range picker with time picker
    $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    locale: {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
    }
    })
    //Date range as a button
    $('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
    {
        ranges   : {
        'Today'       : [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday'   : [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days' : [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month'  : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month'  : [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
        endDate  : moment()
    },
    function (start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        startDate = start;
        endDate = end; 
    }
    )
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
      console.log(startDate.format('D MMMM YYYY') + ' - ' + endDate.format('D MMMM YYYY'));
    });
    //Timepicker
    $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT'
    })

    //Bootstrap Duallistbox
    $('.duallistbox').bootstrapDualListbox()

    //Colorpicker
    $('.my-colorpicker1').colorpicker()
    //color picker with addon
    $('.my-colorpicker2').colorpicker()

    $('.my-colorpicker2').on('colorpickerChange', function(event) {
    $('.my-colorpicker2 .fa-square').css('color', event.color.toString());
    });

    $("input[data-bootstrap-switch]").each(function(){
    $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
})
```

Here is the screenshot first form work properly
[image: first form work properly]
Here is the screenshot second form doesnt work properly
[image: second form doesnt work properly]
Can you guys give me some suggestion how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you are creating datepicker dynamically after running the JQuery code for initialization. You can put the code for init datepicker into a javascript function and call it on-load and after dynamically creating date picker

Comment: thank you so much now my code works properly I realize that I made a mistake when creating the datepicker @NIKHIL